# React weird Firefox error

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I've a react app and I'm getting this `TypeError` in Firefox, latest version, on chrome and safari it works fine.

```
message: "t.linkNamed(...).fetch(...).then(...).finally is not a function"
stack: "[1017]/h</t.prototype._fetch....."
```

I tried to debug it without much success. Any ideas?

Comment: this is the error . So where is your  code ?

Comment: the code is a full app, I have no idea, what is causing it, I've worked only on chrome, just to see that it doesn't work on firefox.

Comment: what is the version of your firefox?

Comment: firefox quantum

Comment: Even it is new and high performance (fast) , firefox quantum is not good as dev environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that `fetch` is supported on Chrome before it has been supported in your firefox . So it seems you are not using the native fetch . Even though, the response streaming is only supported on Chrome  :

So you have two options:

- Either add a polyfill for fetch.
- Or migrate to another http client.

[image]

REFERENCE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: i think none of them supports `.finally` anyway.